# Best Way of Finding out How a Customer Purchased a product

Tags: html, membership, newsletter

What is the best way to find out if a customer has purchased a product instore, as a result of visiting the website?  Would a membership card be a good idea, or something like an email newsletter with offers for that specific store?  Keeping in mind, the product may only be bought less than a handful of times in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

If you give a product a unique code, in addition to it's web id.  The unique code could only be redeemed instore in exchange for a free gift or instore only discount.  That way the volume of sales can only be attributed to the unique code!!

Volterony

Comment: That is a good start.  The purpose of this, which I accidentally neglected to explain, is for an external company to be able to track commission they are owed. Is there a way to enforce that, via a method similar to what you have mentioned? I am just wondering if the store would check a code via a salesperson just looking at it, and not telling the external company that someone used the code.

Comment: What you could do is add an additional field in the product table in the database called offer_code. Then when you scan a product at the till it will flag as having an offer.  There you could do what you like ie get prompted at the till to enter offer code and put the sale through. Then in your sales/till stats you can then filter by offer

Comment: Thank you for answering this.  I assume there's no way to do this without a till?  Good answer either way.